# Missing "out" folder when building a static site with Nx (16.9.0) and NextJS (14.0.4)

Tags: next.js, nrwl-nx

I'm currently using NextJS (14.0.4) and Nx (16.9.0) to build a static site using the "output: 'export'" parameter in my next.config.js as detailed in the [NextJS docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/deploying/static-exports).  Here is the next.config.js file that I am using:

[image]

And here are my library versions:

[image]
[image]

The result of the build process generates static files in a folder called "dist/apps/myApp/.next" and I am able to successfully use these files to deploy a static website.  No complaints so far!

However, my question is whether I should be seeing an "out" folder somewhere as described in the NextJS docs or if the "out" folder in this case is the ".next" directory.  For easy reference, here is a screenshot from the NextJS docs that mention the "out" folder.

[image]

The main reason for my question is I'm not sure if I should be using the files directly from the ".next" folder or if I should be using the files from the "out" folder.  The tutorials I've read online seem to mostly use the files in the ".next" folder but I've also read in a few places that these files should not be used directly.

Any advice would be much appreciated!